# How can i validate a serializer field with ModelSerializer. Does the validate() method get called on create or do i have to call the method

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer (ModelSerializer) where i need to validate a field which will be passed to the validate method.

**CompanySerializer**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_vat_number(self, vat_no):

        vatlayer = "http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key={api_key}&vat_number={VAT_NUMBER}".format(api_key=settings.VATLAYER, VAT_NUMBER=vat_no)

        vatlayer = json.loads(vatlayer)

        if vatlayer['valid'] is not True:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("VAT number not valid")

        return vat_no

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('profile', 'name', 'address', 'currency', 'id_number', 'vat_number', 'vat_company_name', 'email', 'phone', 'fixed_phone')
```

My question is, does the validate_vat_number method get called when the create method is triggered, and if so, how do i pass the vat_no parameter? If not, where do i call this method? And is it possible to do it without overwriting the create method?

**My view**

```
class CompanyAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

It would be perfect if i could somehow validate without using @action in the view since that makes another endpoint. My goal is to validate and save the object with one post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the validation order:

1. Field deserialization ([serializer.to_internal_value](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L374) and [field.run_validators](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L397))
2. [serializer.validate_[field]](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L399) is called for each field
3. Serializer-level validators are called ([serializer.run_validation](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L186))
4. [serializer.validate](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L367)
5. [create method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/serializers.py#L399) is called after all validations completed.

So in your case, since it's not an actually field error but rather a verification error, you should use [object level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) (step 4):

```
def validate(self, data):
    vatlayer = "http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key={api_key}&vat_number={VAT_NUMBER}".format(api_key=settings.VATLAYER, VAT_NUMBER=data[vat_no])

    vatlayer = json.loads(vatlayer)

    if vatlayer['valid'] is not True:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("VAT number not valid")

    return data
```